# Does 32 or 64-bits CPU use segmentation addressing on Linux?

Tags: memory, cpu

Does 32 or 64-bits CPU use segmentation addressing on Linux? I know on older CPUs like the 8086 used segmentation for memory addressing but not sure if this method is used on 32-bit or 64-bit CPUs for Linux operating system.

Answer (score 5):

Originally (before the 286) segmentation was mostly a hack designed to make it possible to address more than 64KB on a 16 bit CPU. In 286 protected mode segmentation was extended to introduce protection and extended the physical memory supported from 1MB to 16MB. But the CPU still only had 16 bit registers which meant that any contiguous block of data larger than 64KB was problematic to process.

All of that changed with the introduction of the 386. CPU registers were extended to 32 bits, and paging was added as a new feature. Paging was a much more powerful way to map between logical and physical addresses than what was achievable with segmentation.

Linux was originally designed for the 386 and made use of the paging feature. Linux use of segmentation was minimal, some of the protection settings were controlled through segment descriptors which meant that you could not completely avoid the need for segmentation. But Linux would configure all segments to start at address 0.

In other words: Linux never used segmented addressing. It only used segmentation because that was required to control some of the protection features.

When AMD designed the 64 bit CPUs they decided that some historical features would not be supported in 64 bit mode. One of the things they did was to enforce a segment start address of 0. So at that point segmented addresses were no longer supported neither by hardware nor software.

If you run a modern CPU in 16 or 32 bit mode it still supports segmented addresses for backward compatibility. But in 64 bit mode you only have 64 bit linear addresses and paging.

Comment: Nice summary of the basics. And to make this even more clear: Any 64 bit OS (not just Linux) does without segmentation as the CPU just can't do it. For 32-bit OS: some still use segmentation for backwards compatibility with specific legacy code (Linux, Windows prior to 10), while other OS have completely done away with it. E.g Window 10 32-bit still exists (as a nice OS for some limited hardware platforms), but AFAIK  doesn't have/need backwards compatibility at this level and doesn't support it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The 8086 didn't really have an MMU comparable with what modern x86 CPUs do; with 386 and later on, things were radically different:

- arbitrarily many virtual memory regions
- page tables to map these
- Nested page tables just to make things work more easily
- further forms of virtualization

It's a pretty complex topic, and I don't think a concise overview over the x86 memory management architecture can just be given within a superuser answer. However, segmentation is not one of the terms one would use to describe that architecture. I'm afraid I can only ask you to read an article on the 386 and operating system design for x86.